Computing the relative error of two Runge Kutta Methods for Convergence Analysis
I am currently endeavoring to assess the relative error between the classical Runge-Kutta (RK4) method and another RK variant. I've opted to employ the Ordinary Differential Equation (ODE) governing a physical pendulum as the exemplar scenario. Upon specifying a step size and end time, I generate solutions and store the angular values produced by both methods in separate lists. Subsequently, I compile another list housing the angular values from a reference method. The next step involves calculating the L2 Norm of the list obtained by subtracting the reference angular values from those obtained through the RK4 method. This resultant value is then divided by the L2 Norm of the reference angular values.
Mathematically, this computation can be represented as follows:
relative_error = np.linalg.norm(phi - reference_phi) / np.linalg.norm(reference_phi)

Effectively, I obtain two scalar values: the relative error for the RK4 method and the relative error for the alternate RK4 variant based on another predefined method. My query pertains to the suitability of this error calculation formula for convergence analysis of method behavior. If this approach is deemed acceptable, I am curious as to which method should serve as the reference for comparison. I am contemplating either utilizing the Radau method or reverting to the RK4 method albeit with a reduced step size for this purpose.
